# Length of DataFrame doesn't change after dropping rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new into using pandas and I haven't found a solution for this specific problem while searching around here. For some reason, after dropping some rows, the shape of my DataFrame changes but when exploring the DataFrame, it still shows me the rows I thought I dropped.

I am confused, and due to this a lot of issues occur later on in my code.

Here is the problematic part:

```
data_removed_more_cols = new_data.drop(columns=["overview", "tagline", "video", "original_title", "id"])
data_released = data_removed_more_cols["Released" == data_removed_more_cols["status"]].drop(columns=["status"])
print("Shape: " + str(data_released.shape[0]))
print(data_released)
```

And the output I get is:

```
Shape: 363016
        adult  ...               streaming_platform_US
0       False  ...                   Criterion Channel
1       False  ...                   Criterion Channel
2       False  ...                                 NaN
3       False  ...                                 NaN
4       False  ...  DocAlliance Films|GuideDoc|realeyz
...       ...  ...                                 ...
364057  False  ...                                 NaN
364058  False  ...                                 NaN
364059  False  ...                                 NaN
364061  False  ...                  Amazon Prime Video
364062  False  ...                                 NaN

[363016 rows x 21 columns]
```

Notice how print(data_released) will show me 364062 rows, while at the same time telling me that the shape of the DF is 363016 rows.

EDIT: As Henry mentioned in the comments, I needed to use data_released.reset_index(drop=True). That fixed my problem.

Comment: In your print output the printed `Shape: 363016` and number of rows (`[363016 rows x 21 columns]`) are both `363016`. If you're talking about the _index_ of the dataframe. That will be unchanged when filtering rows. If you want to reset the index use `data_released.reset_index(drop=True)` [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index)

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes, but if you look into the data in the middle of the output it shows you the rows 364057 to 364062, and they shouldn't exist. EDIT: Yes, thank you! I needed to drop the index, I didn't know that.